# didReceiveNotificationRequest:withContentHandler - execution time limit?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, serviceextension

[`UNNotificationServiceExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension?language=objc) has a method  [`didReceiveNotificationRequest:withContentHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension/1648229-didreceivenotificationrequest?language=objc) to handle notification change.

It has a very ambiguous description, regarding timeout time:

> That method has a limited amount of time to perform its task and execute the provided completion block. If your method does not finish in time,

And here's a description of [`serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension/1648227-serviceextensiontimewillexpire?language=objc) method:

> If your didReceiveNotificationRequest:withContentHandler: method takes to long to execute its completion block, the system calls this method on a separate thread to give you one last chance to execute the block.

I don't fully get, what "***to long to execute***" means. **Does it have any quantitative data?** Does it vary on device it runs, etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension/1648229-didreceivenotificationrequest?language=objc#discussion

Taken from Apple docs above link.

Your extension has a limited amount of time **(no more than 30 seconds)** to modify the content and execute the contentHandler block.